# Sum of NaNs to equal NaN (not zero)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum, nan, zero

I can add a TOTAL column to this DF using df['TOTAL'] = df.sum(axis=1), and it adds the row elements like this:

```
   col1  col2  TOTAL
0   1.0   5.0    6.0
1   2.0   6.0    8.0
2   0.0   NaN    0.0
3   NaN   NaN    0.0
```

However, I would like the total of the bottom row to be NaN, not zero, like this:

```
   col1  col2  TOTAL
0   1.0   5.0    6.0
1   2.0   6.0    8.0
2   0.0   NaN    0.0
3   NaN   NaN    Nan
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in a performant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parameter `min_count=1` to [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

> **min_count** : int, default 0
>   The required number of valid values to perform the operation. If fewer than min_count non-NA values are present the result will be NA.
>
> New in version 0.22.0: Added with the default being 0. This means the sum of an all-NA or empty Series is 0, and the product of an all-NA or empty Series is 1.

```
df['TOTAL'] = df.sum(axis=1, min_count=1)
print (df)
   col1  col2  TOTAL
0   1.0   5.0    6.0
1   2.0   6.0    8.0
2   0.0   NaN    0.0
3   NaN   NaN    NaN
```